# Highlighting specific records in classic ASP

Tags: arrays, loops, asp-classic, record

In my [quiz page](http://cauverycars.com/yaseen/quizModule02_08.asp), I have ten questions. When the user goes through these questions, I store the IDs of wrong questions in a array. When the user clicks on the "show result" link, I'm going to display all 10 questions with their answers. I want to highlight wrongly answered question with bold letters.

Here's my code:

```
Dim DB_CONN_STRING
DB_CONN_STRING = "DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("quiz.mdb") & ";"
DB_CONN_STRING = DB_CONN_STRING & "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};"
DB_CONN_STRING = DB_CONN_STRING & "DriverId=25;FIL=MS Access;"

Const QUIZ_ID = 1

Dim panswer 

panswer=split((Request.QueryString("marked")),",")

''# collecting wrongly answered question id in panswer
Dim cnnQuiz, rsQuiz, I
Set cnnQuiz = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cnnQuiz.Open DB_CONN_STRING
Set rsQuiz = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsQuiz.Open "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE quiz_id=" & QUIZ_ID & " ORDER BY question_number;", cnnQuiz, 3, 1
Do While Not rsQuiz.EOF
    For  I = LBound(panswer) to UBound(panswer)
        if (CStr(rsQuiz.Fields("question_number").Value)) = CStr(panswer(i)) then
            ''# testing whether this question is wrongly answered and if its true then making bold letters.
            response.Write("<b>"&(rsQuiz.Fields("question_number").Value)&")</b>") 
            response.Write("<b>"&(rsQuiz.Fields("question_text").Value)&"</b><br>")
            response.Write("<b>"&(rsQuiz.Fields("correct_answer").Value)&"</b><br>")
        end if
    Next 
    '' # else displaying all 10 questions
    response.Write((rsQuiz.Fields("question_number").Value)&") ") 
    response.Write((rsQuiz.Fields("question_text").Value)&"<br>")
    response.Write((rsQuiz.Fields("correct_answer").Value)&"<br>")
    rsQuiz.MoveNext
Loop
rsQuiz.Close
Set rsQuiz = Nothing
cnnQuiz.Close
Set cnnQuiz = Nothing
```

Problem: this code displays all 10 records, but only the first item in the array gets highlighted, and it repeats twice. This is an existing website and I have to keep to classic ASP.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you should be using the loop to determine whether the make bold or not but not include output in the loop.  Then use a simple if to send one output or the other.

```
Dim DB_CONN_STRING
DB_CONN_STRING = "DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("quiz.mdb") & ";"
DB_CONN_STRING = DB_CONN_STRING & "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};"
DB_CONN_STRING = DB_CONN_STRING & "DriverId=25;FIL=MS Access;"

Const QUIZ_ID = 1

Dim panswer 

panswer=split((Request.QueryString("marked")),",")

''# collecting wrongly answered question id in panswer
Dim cnnQuiz, rsQuiz, I
Set cnnQuiz = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cnnQuiz.Open DB_CONN_STRING
Set rsQuiz = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsQuiz.Open "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE quiz_id=" & QUIZ_ID & " ORDER BY question_number;", cnnQuiz, 3, 1

Dim bMakeBold
Do While Not rsQuiz.EOF

    bMakeBold = False;
    For  I = LBound(panswer) to UBound(panswer)
        ''# testing whether this question is wrongly answered and if its true then making bold letters.
        If (CStr(rsQuiz.Fields("question_number").Value)) = CStr(panswer(i)) Then
            bMakeBold = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    if bMakeBold then 
        response.Write("<b>"&(rsQuiz.Fields("question_number").Value)&")</b>") 
        response.Write("<b>"&(rsQuiz.Fields("question_text").Value)&"</b><br>")
        response.Write("<b>"&(rsQuiz.Fields("correct_answer").Value)&"</b><br>")
    else
        response.Write((rsQuiz.Fields("question_number").Value)&") ") 
        response.Write((rsQuiz.Fields("question_text").Value)&"<br>")
        response.Write((rsQuiz.Fields("correct_answer").Value)&"<br>")
    end if

    rsQuiz.MoveNext
Loop
rsQuiz.Close
Set rsQuiz = Nothing
cnnQuiz.Close
Set cnnQuiz = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony, This approach looks simple and straight forward, the problem was in my code is when i am collecting array it was adding one space along with id like (1, 8 , 9 )etc except first record, so only first record was becoming bold, <br> <br>

If (CStr(rsQuiz.Fields("question_number").Value)) = CStr(panswer(i)) Then 
<br><br>
so this statement becomes true only once for first record. 

Thanks you very much for your time and Solution.